# Client-side Replication for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, replication

I'd like to have some degree of fault tolerance / redundancy with my SQL Server Express database.  I know that if I upgrade to a pricier version of SQL Server, I can get "Replication" built in.  But I'm wondering if anyone has experience in managing replication on the *client side*.  As in, from my application:

- Every time I need to create, update or delete records from the database -- issue the statement to all *n* servers directly from the client side
- Every time I need to read, I can do so from one representative server (other schemes seem possible here, too).
- It seems like this logic could potentially be added directly to my Linq-To-SQL Data Context.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

> Every time I need to create, update or
>   delete records from the database --
>   issue the statement to all n servers
>   directly from the client side

Recipe for disaster.

Are you going to have a distributed transaction or just let some of the servers fail?  If you have a distributed transaction, what do you do if a server goes offline for a while.

This type of thing can only work if you do it at a server-side data-portal layer where application servers take in your requests and are aware of your database farm.  At that point, you're better off just using a higher grade of SQL Server.

Comment: But if one of the databases went offline or died, and therefore didn't respond to my INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE -- wouldn't that be the 'canary in the coal mine' I'm looking for?  I could then sound an alarm that a database server has died, and -- in the interim -- only communicate with the remaining, healthy server[s].  Right?

Comment: And doing server-side replication isn't currently an option, due to financial constraints.  So the real question is: is client side replication better than just frequent backup of the Express database.

Comment: @Mighty Z Have you added up the development time to make a reliable "client-side" solution vs. a different SQL Server Edition?  And yes, you can do hourly full backups with half-hourly log backups, say, of a database limited to Express' size limit very easily.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed replication from an in-house client. My database model worked on an insert-only mode for all transactions, and insert-update for lookup data.  Deletes were not allowed.

I had a central table that everything was related to. I added a field to this table for a date-time stamp which defaulted to NULL.  I took data from this table and all related tables into a staging area, did BCP out, cleaned up staging tables on the receiver side, did a BCP IN to staging tables, performed data validation and then inserted the data.

For some basic Fault Tolerance, you can scheduling a regular backup.